# HTML/CSS: I can't get rid of whitespace at the bottom a page

Tags: html, css

I have a large amount of whitespace at the bottom of my page that I can't seem to get rid of. I have a `<div class="container">` wrapping all of my code, and when I get rid of it the whitespace does go away but all of my positioning gets messed up. I also have the bootstrap links in my page, but I'm not really using bootstrap for anything... But when I remove the links, all of my CSS disappears... Could that be part of the problem? I've tried numerous things using

```
html, body {

}
```

but none of it seems to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>All Quizes</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="javesheet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<div class="logo">
  <p>Insert logo link here...</p>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="feature-content">
      <p>Featured Quiz</p>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="rails-quiz">
    <div class="rails-quiz-content">
      <img src="ruby.png">
      <p>Rails Quiz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rails-start-button">
    <p>Start</p>
  </div>

  <div class="js-quiz">
    <div class="js-quiz-content">
      <img src="javascript.png">
      <p>JavaScript Quiz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="js-start-button">
    <p>Start</p>
  </div>

  <div class="html-css-quiz">
    <div class="html-css-quiz-content">
      <img src="html.png">
      <p>HTML/CSS Quiz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="html-css-start-button">
    <p>Start</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-1">
    <h1>Rails</h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-2">
    <h1>JavaScript</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-3">
    <h1>HTML & CSS</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container { border: 1px solid red; }

.logo {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.feature {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #008080;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 150px;
  opacity: .9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.feature-content {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.rails-quiz {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #008080;
  opacity: .9;
  top: 220px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}


.rails-quiz-content {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.rails-start-button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 115px;
  left: 90px;
  opacity: .5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}



.js-start-button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: -220px;
  left: 440px;
  opacity: .5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.html-css-start-button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: -545px;
  left: 790px;
  opacity: .5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.js-quiz {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #008080;
  opacity: .9;
  top: -110px;
  left: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.js-quiz-content {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.html-css-quiz {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #008080;
  opacity: .9;
  top: -440px;
  left: 700px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.html-css-quiz-content {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.bottom-1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #99cccc;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -420px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.bottom-2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #99cccc;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -740px;
  left: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.bottom-3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #99cccc;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -1060px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 700px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code somewhere?

Comment: Yes, your CSS would be very valuable in analyzing the issue.

Comment: @skribe just updated with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: it's the negative position on `.bottom-3` causes the problem.

```
.bottom-3 {
    top: -1060px;
    margin-bottom: -1060px; /* add this */
}
```

And adjust that value as needed.

Comment: Hm I tried this and it didn't seem to work, and the red border shows that it is my container going all the way down to the page. I updated my post with all of my html and css.

Comment: Updated the answer, can you give it a try and see?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the any padding or margins to come from the `html` or `body` elements, then you must do this:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is so that the padding and margins are actually canceled out.

```
html, body {

}
```

Will just try to stack on top of the existing rules (which is where the padding and margin are coming from), as opposed to overriding them.

Comment: OP mentioned about **large amount**, there must be something else, but we don't know.

Comment: Yes there is a very large amount, I've already tried playing around with the html, body {} but I can't seem to get anything working. When I delete my container tag the space does go away, but all of my positioning is then messed up.